# Is there a way to find the mac address of a remote machine I have connected to with ssh?

Tags: ssh, mac-address, wake-on-lan

I have machine at the office which is shut off I was hoping to turn it on from home using wake on lan. Reading about this, I have realized that I need the MAC address of the machine. Is there a way to find the MAC address of the machine from my ssh connection history?

I use an RSA key to connect to the machine.

Comment: If you have access to the DHCP server, possible LDAP database, its nearest router or managed switch it *may* be possible to get the MAC with some detective skills.

Comment: Even if you were able to find the MAC address, you wouldn't be able to do anything with it. The MAC address only has any use if you can send packets on the same Ethernet segment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, ssh has nothing to do with MAC addresses. If you are using DHCP you can maybe look into the logs or configuration files to determine the mac address.

Answer (score 0):

WOL has to be enabled to use it (normally a BIOS setting). If you know which port on a switch or router is connected to your target system you might find the MAC in the log-history of that network device.

Comment: Thanks. It was a long shot to begin with. The issue is that I have an Idea that I need the machine to test it on and I won't have access to it until Monday. I was hopping that the sysadmin has enables WOL on that machine.